# Markov chain period

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Let a Markov chain with State space $E=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and probability transition matrix:

$$P=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\ 1/4 & 0 & 1/4 & 1/2\\0 & 1& 0 & 0  \\ 0 &1/2&0&1/2  \end{bmatrix}$$

How can I find the period of the chain?

---

I think the states 1,2,3 are periodic with period 2 and 4 is aperiodic because there is a loop.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you drawn a diagram of the chain? Which states do you think are periodic and which of them are aperiodic?

Comment: I think the states 1,2,3 are periodic with period 2 and 4 is aperiodic because there is a loop.

Comment: This is not a transition matrix.

Comment: I correct the error in the last line.

Comment: Okay, this answer the third question in my previous comment. But what about the first one? What have you tried? What are your thoughts on the problem? What do you have to show in order to prove (a)periodicity ...?

Comment: The chain is aperiodic if there is a loop?

Comment: @GiulyB The chain is aperiodic if *all* states are aperiodic and so far we do not know this, right? Okay, so there is a loop at state $4$ and therefore $4$ is aperiodic, I agree. What about the remaining ones? Any idea how to prove that they have period 2?

Comment: $p^2(1,1)=1/4=p^2(2,2)=p^2(3,3)=p^2(4,4)$

Comment: @GiulyB Well, what does this tell us? A state $i$ is (in general) **not** periodic with period $2$ if $p^2(i,i)>0$. What do you really have to show?

Comment: I define $N_x=\{n>0: p^n(x,x)>0\}$ and $d=M.C.D.\{N_x\}$; I have $N_x=\{1,2,3,4\}$ so M.C.D. is 1?

Comment: What you have shown (in your last comment) is that $2 \in N_x$ for all $x \in \{1,2,3,4\}$. This implies $d_x = gcd(N_x) \in \{1,2\}$. It remains to decide whether $d_x = 1$ or $d_x = 2$ for $x \in \{1,2,3\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Set $\DeclareMathOperator \gcd{gcd}$

$$N_x := \{n \in \mathbb{N}; p^n(x,x)>0\} \qquad \quad d_x := \gcd(N_x).$$

- state 4: Since $p(4,4) = \frac{1}{2}>0$, it follows that $p^n(4,4)>0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$; hence, $N_4 = \mathbb{N}$ and $d_4 = \gcd(\mathbb{N})=1$, i.e. state $4$ is aperiodic.
- state 3: We have $$p^2(3,3) =  \mathbb{P}^3(X_2 = 3) \geq \mathbb{P}^3(X_2 = 3, X_1 = 2) = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{4} >0,$$ i.e. $2 \in N_3$. Moreover, $$\begin{align*} p^5(3,3) &= \mathbb{P}^3(X_5 = 3) \\ &\geq \mathbb{P}^3(X_1 = 2, X_2 = 4, X_3 = 4, X_4 = 2, X_5 = 3) \\ &= 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{4} >0. \end{align*}$$ Consequently, $5 \in N_3$ and this implies $d_3 \leq \gcd(2,5)= 1$.

The argumentation for state 1 and 2 is similar, I leave it to you.

Comment: so which is the period of the chain?

Comment: @GiulyB What conclusion did you draw for state 1 and 2? I won't solve your homework for you.

Comment: also $d_2\leq gdc(2,5)$ and $d_1\leq gdc(2,5)$.All the states have period 1 so the chain is aperiodic.

Comment: @GiulyB Yes, that's correct.